# Ionic: Running APK in local host?

Tags: ionic-framework, apk

Is it possible to run an APK on an Ionic or any other localhost? Meaning I'm able to open my app intro a browser

Comment: Duplicated question. Does this answer your question? [How to Debug Ionic WebApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678851/how-to-debug-ionic-webapp)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can preview your builded apk its using chrome inspect. You must have it running in your cellphone and connected to the pc.

Open chrome and paste this url: `chrome://inspect/#devices`

Good luck!